# Decentralized identity vs Decentralized identifiers

Tags: decentralized-identity, decentralized-identifiers

I am a newbie to decentralized identity concept. While I am reading on that, I notice two similar terminologies;
Decentralized identity and Decentralized identifiers

I am wondering whether Decentralized identity and Decentralized identifiers are two different concept.
If so, what is the different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are different.

In simply,

- **Decentralized identity is an identity management** that which define how to allow entities to generate, manage and control personally identifiable information (PII) without a identity provider or certification authority.
- **Decentralized identifier (DID) is just a unique identifier that identifies an entity**. DID is a core component that enables decentralized digital identity.